# Creating a reuseable vertical navbar that always fit

Tags: html, css

I want to create a secondary vertical navbar component, that can be passed into any div, and it will automatically fill it from top to bottom, with some fixed width

Something like this (doesnt work correctly obviously as it goes under the topnav)

[image]

My attempt:

```
<div class="context-menu">
    <div class="">
      <ul class="menu">
        {{#each state$items}}
          <li class=""><a href=""><i class="{{icon}}"></i> {{text}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

.context-menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: @gray-dark;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {

    width: @secondary-sidebar-width;

    .navbar-nav li {
      float: none !important;
    }
  }
}
```

But as can be seen, this doesnt function properly. How can I make sure that it always fit the div it's placed inside?

Comment: You need to make sure that any div that acts as the host (parent) for the menu has their `position` set to `relative`, so they act as the anchor for the freely positioned element.

Comment: When you say fit the div it's placed inside do you mean height? or do you want the div to be positioned relatively to the parent?